Stochastic Op bound for max of set of stochastic processes.
Let $X = \{X_1, \dots, X_p \}$ be a set of stochastic processes such that $X_i = O_p(a_n) \; \forall i$.
Is it true that $\max{X} = O_p(a_n)$ ?

My attempt:
Let $\epsilon > 0$ we know that there exists $\delta$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \geq \delta a_n) \leq \epsilon / p \; , \dots , \; \mathbb{P}(X_p \geq \delta a_n) \leq \epsilon / p \quad \forall n > N$$
Then we have
$$\mathbb{P}(\max{X} \geq \delta a_n) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^p \{{X_i} \geq \delta a_n\})  \leq \sum_{i=1}^p \mathbb{P}( {X_i} \geq \delta a_n) \leq p \epsilon /p =\epsilon $$
Therefore as $\mathbb{P}(\max{X} \geq \delta a_n) \leq \epsilon$, then  $\max{X} = O_p(a_n)$.

Then what about if $p$, the number of random variables in the set, is going to infinity.

I think I understand now.
So it is indeed true if $p$, the number of stochastic processes, is fixed then $\max{X} = O_p(a_n)$.
However if the $p$ is now a function of $n$, for example, in HDS, then this is no longer necessarily true.
For example, if we let $p=n$ then we cannot in general write:
For some $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \geq \delta a_n) \leq \epsilon / p \; , \dots , \; \mathbb{P}(X_p \geq \delta a_n) \leq \epsilon / p \quad \forall n > N$$
Because $\epsilon / p = \epsilon / n$ this quantity is not fixed and so we cannot say from the definition that there exists an $N$ such that the inequality holds. This is a similar question, where the discussion explains the problem.
